# CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);

Tags: webview, gtk, vala

```
WebView wv=new WebView();
wv.load_uri("http://www.twitter.com");
```

how to allow cookies?

I read

```
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
```

But I can not find the right syntax

> valac --pkg gtk+-3.0 --pkg webkit2gtk-4.0 wv.vala && ./wv
>   wv.vala:25.2-25.26: error: The name 'getInstance' does not exist in the context of 'WebKit.CookieManager'
>       CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);

Comment: getInstance method does not exist. CookieManager has a set_accept_policy method that you can try, eg, `CookieManager.set_accept_policy(CookieAcceptPolicy.ALWAYS)`.

Comment: Sorry for the response time
and thank you for the answer

Comment: Sorry for the response time
thank you for the answer
result :
error: Access to instance member `WebKit.CookieManager.set_accept_policy' denied
 CookieManager.set_accept_policy(CookieAcceptPolicy.ALWAYS);

Comment: You must have an instance of CookieManager. This method is an instance method not a class method. Let me check with a real example.

Comment: You must use something like: `wv.get_context ().get_cookie_manager ().set_accept_policy (CookieAcceptPolicy.ALWAYS)`. To get the cookie Manager you need the webview context and then get the cookie manager from the context data manager.

Comment: Thank you very much: everything works

using Gtk;
using WebKit;
public Gtk.Window window;
int main (string[] args) {
    Gtk.init(ref args);
    window=new Gtk.Window();
    window.destroy.connect(Gtk.main_quit);
 WebView wv=new WebView();
 wv.get_context().get_cookie_manager ().set_accept_policy(CookieAcceptPolicy.ALWAYS);
 wv.load_uri("https://www.twitter.com");
 window.add(wv);
    window.show_all();
    Gtk.main();
    return 0;
}

Comment: Nice. Good luck

Comment: I can not get into shape, sorry

Answer (score 1):

For Gtk+ 3 and Webkit2Gtk-4.0, cookie acceptance/denial is controlled by the CookieManager which you can retrieve from the Webkit [web context](https://valadoc.org/webkit2gtk-4.0/WebKit.WebContext.html) data manager.

Using your supplied code:

```
using Gtk;
using WebKit;

public int main (string[] args) { 
    Gtk.Window window;

    Gtk.init(ref args);

    window = new Gtk.Window();
    window.destroy.connect(Gtk.main_quit);

    WebView wv=new WebView();
    wv.get_context().get_cookie_manager ().set_accept_policy(CookieAcceptPolicy.ALWAYS);

    window.add(wv);
    window.show_all();

    //wv.load_uri("http://www.html-kit.com/tools/cookietester");
    wv.load_uri("http://www.whatarecookies.com/cookietest.asp");

    Gtk.main();

    return 0;
}
```

Verifying [CookieAcceptPolicy](https://valadoc.org/webkit2gtk-4.0/WebKit.CookieAcceptPolicy.html) with the supplied examples,

**Setting accept always:**

```
wv.get_context().get_cookie_manager ().set_accept_policy(CookieAcceptPolicy.ALWAYS);
```

A test site will reply with:

[image: AcceptAlways]

**Setting accept never:**

```
wv.get_context().get_cookie_manager ().set_accept_policy(CookieAcceptPolicy.NEVER);
```

A test site will reply with:

[image: AcceptNever]

**EDIT:**

Compile with:

```
valac --pkg gtk+-3.0 --pkg webkit2gtk-4.0 <your-filename.vala>
```